# Random image click

Tags: javascript, image

So I got a site full of images and they are are all in random order, everytime you refresh the page. You have to search for a image which is always on a different place.

```
function randomWaldo() {
var randomNummer = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[randomNummer].src = "images/waldo.jpg";}
```

Now I want the first paragraph in my HTML to change when you click on that one image. How can I do this?

Comment: Please include your html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to select the image who have the wanted source.

And add a class or id to your paragraph for readability.

```
document.querySelectorAll("img[src='images/waldo.jpg']")[0].onclick=function()
{
document.getElementById("paragraphid").innerHTML="You win";
};
```

**Example**

```js
document.querySelectorAll("img[src='image/waldo.jpg']")[0].onclick=function()
{
  document.getElementById("rep").innerHTML="you win !";
}
```

```css
img{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  }
```

```html
<p id="rep"></p>
<img src="image/nok.jpg" alt="nok">
<img src="image/nok.jpg" alt="nok">
<img src="image/nok.jpg" alt="nok">
<img src="image/waldo.jpg" alt="waldo">
<img src="image/nok.jpg" alt="nok">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
//find all paragraphs
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
//define function called on click
function changeParagraph() {
  //change first paragraph if exists
  if(paragraphs.length) {
        paragraphs[0].innerHTML = 'I have been changed!';
  }
}
/*
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    //set onclick event to every image
    images[i].onclick = changeParagraph;
}
*/
// set onclick to the randomImage
images[randomNumber].onclick = changeParagraph;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your first paragraph exists before the user clicks the picture, you can add an onClick element to your img tag. Try something like this, changing the URL obviously for your own picture:

```
 <p id = "first">You haven't found Waldo
</p>
     <img id = "waldo" src = https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/561277979855056896/4yRcS2Zo.png 
        onclick = "addparagraph()"
        />
```

JavaScript:

```
function addparagraph(){
    document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = "you found Waldo!";
}
```